# How to sort files in Nautilus by multiple attributes?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

Is it possible to sort files in Nautilus by multiple attributes (e.g. first by type and second by name) globally? I.e. can I do this without having to first click on one column and on another one afterwards, everytime I open a folder/directory?